# Suitable protocol between a raspberry pi and a local connected (no cloud) spark core

Tags: php, python, c++, c, mqtt

I want to be able to communicate between a spark core and a raspberry pi using WiFi. I want to create a persistent connection. I also want to be able to create server side functionality on the raspberry pi that enables me to create a web-page where I can get spark core sent data to the web-page, and also be able to send commands to the spark core.

Comment: I would use sockets? Im not sure what the question actually is here ...

Comment: Hmm, sockets come in many shapes, but sure maybe my question is not clear enough...I want to have a web page where I can get server events from the raspberry that has been triggered by updates from from the spark. In this case we are talking about 2-60 bytes back and forth and I want minimum latency?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite open question as a lot of different solutions could arise here. If you want for instance to try with *MQTT* look at this:

a) Use an *MQTT client* that works on *spark core* like:
https://community.spark.io/t/submission-mqtt-library-and-sample/2111

b) Use an *MQTT broker* in the *raspberry pi* like Mosquitto:
http://mosquitto.org/download/

The *spark core* can publish/subscribe to messages in the *MQTT broker* running in the *raspberry pi*.

With the `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub` clients, the *raspberry pi* can also publish/subscribe to messages into its broker.

c) Connect the *raspberry pi* clients to the web application via a server engine. Or directly in your web application via the *javascript/websockets* Mosquitto client.

Comment: I'll try mqtt asap, and test the latency, next I'll try sse. I've tried rest and an http server on the spark seems very unstable, can't get the connection stable (want some kind of persistent connection). I know my question is broad, but think this is one way to narrow the it down to suit my needs.

Comment: Thanks Teixi for you quick answer.